# No data displayed using date parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a column in my SQL Server 2017 database which stores a date as `datetime`. I have a SQL query to select all products that where sold in specific date range unfortunately no data is returned. Data is only returned when I hardcode the input parameters in my SQL.

SQL query is as below, I also tried try_convert function

```
SELECT product_name, date_sold
FROM .......
WHERE date_sold BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar, @start_date, 23) 
                    AND CONVERT(varchar, @end_date, 23)
```

Comment: If your date is a `datetime`, why are you converting to `varchar`? And you should always define the length of `varchar`.

Comment: Why are you converting the parameter data type at all? The column is *datetime*, the @parameter should match.

Comment: This query you shard with us does not throw any errors ?

Comment: You don't have a table?

Comment: *"SQL server 17"* doesn't exist; the latest version is SQL Server 2019, which is SQL Server 15. Do you mean SQL Server **2017**?

Answer (score 0):

Your query works correctly with parameters, as shown below.
As noted in the comments there is no need for the `CONVERT`, it works with or without.
I suggest that you check the initialisation of your paremeters with the query
`SELECT @start_date, @end_date;`

```
create table myTable (product_name varchar(50), date_sold datetime);
insert into myTable values('product 1','2022-03-05'),('product 2','2022-04-05');
```

```
declare @start_date date = '2022-04-01';
declare @end_date date = '2022-04-10';
SELECT @start_date, @end_date;
Select product_name, date_sold
from myTable
Where date_sold between convert(varchar,@start_date,23) and convert(varchar,@end_date,23);
```

```
(No column name) | (No column name)
:--------------- | :---------------
2022-04-01       | 2022-04-10      

product_name | date_sold              
:----------- | :----------------------
product 2    | 2022-04-05 00:00:00.000
declare @start_date date = '2022-04-01';
declare @end_date date = '2022-04-10';
```

```
Select product_name, date_sold
from myTable
Where date_sold between @start_date and @end_date;
```

```
product_name | date_sold              
:----------- | :----------------------
product 2    | 2022-04-05 00:00:00.000
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8d67810ff38d4dcb75dc1fd9b47c91ad)*

Comment: Thank you everyone for your inputs..Resolved